# SQL query - percentage of sub sample

Tags: sql, sum

I got a SQL statement:

```
Select
ID, GroupID, Profit
From table
```

I now want to add a fourth column percentage of group profits.
Therefore the query should sum all the profits for the same group id and then have that number divided by the profit for the unique ID.

Is there a way to do this? The regular sum function does not seem to do the trick.

Thanks

Comment: Is this MySQL? (Most other RDBMSs have windowed functions that can be used to handle this, but MySQL doesn't.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t1.ID, 
       t1. GroupID, 
       (t1.Profit * 1.0) / t2.grp_profit as percentage_profit
from table t1
inner join 
(
   select GroupID, sum(Profit) as grp_profit
   from table
   group by GroupID
) t2 on t1.groupid = t2.groupid
```

Answer (score 2):

One more option with window function

```
select ID, GroupID, Profit * 1. / SUM(profit) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID)
from t1
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using scalar sub-queries is as follows:

```
select t1.ID, t1.GroupID, (select sum(t2.Profit) * 1.0 / t1.Profit 
                           from table t2 
                           where t2.GroupID = t1.GroupID) as percentage_profit
from table t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide an alternate answer, albeit less efficient, is to use a scalar subquery.

```
SELECT  ID, GroupId, Profit, (Profit/(SELECT sum(Profit) 
                                     FROM my_table 
                                     WHERE GroupId= mt.GroupId))*100 as pct
FROM my_table as mt
```

From the way it reads I'm not sure if you want "percentage of group profits" or you or want group_profit / individual profit

That's the way this sounds "Therefore the query should sum all the profits for the same group id and then have that number divided by the profit for the unique ID"

Either way just switch the divisor for what you want!

Also if you're using `Postgresql` >= 8.4 you can use a window function.

```
SELECT ID, GroupId, Profit, (Profit/ (sum(Profit) OVER(partition by GroupId)))*100 as pct
FROM core_dev.my_table as mt
```